# Web service client getting NullPointerException from getMyWSPort

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, jax-ws

I have created a simple web service called `TimeServerBean`. It's working properly, the GlassFish server is running and I can access the WSDL file from browser. Note this is done on local host.

Next I created a new project and made a web service client and provided the URL to the WSDL file. Then I got some classes generated (JAX-WS).
On my client class I have this code:

```
public class SimpleClient {

    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "wsdl url here")
    static TimeServerBean_Service service;
    private TimeServerBean bean;

    public SimpleClient() {
         bean = service.getTimeServerBeanPort();
    }
    //methods here
}
```

Although I get null when I call the `getTimeServerBeanPort`. During that time the server is up and running. Is there some obvious mistake? `TimeServerBean` and `TimeServerBean_Service` are generated classes from the WSDL.

Comment: Is the method returning `null`, or are you getting a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: I don't see a try/catch block.  If you haven't already, please add one, and look at the exception (I'm guessing you probably *will* get an exception).

Comment: My semieducated guess is that `@WebServiceRef` is an annotation an application server's dependency injection mechanism looks for, and automatically instantiates a `TimeServerBean_Service` for you. What kind of application is `SimpleClient` used in? If it's a web application, consider getting the service object from a "web" object that Glassfish is aware of. If it's a standalone application, you'll have to instantiate the service object yourself. Hopefully someone more familiar with JAX-WS will answer this better.

Comment: What container are you running the client in and how are you creating the SimpleClient instance?

Comment: SimpleClient is a Web Service Client created using a wsdl file and its within a Java Application project in netbeans. I create a new instance of it from a GUI interface.

Comment: You have to instantiate it manually like:`service = new TimeServerBean_Service();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. DEFINITELY put your method in a `try`/`catch` block
2. Assuming that `service` itself is null, then try doing an explicit `service.create()` instead of using the `@WebServiceRef` annotation. Here's a good example (Websphere, but same principle):

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21264135

Comment: Turned out I simple had to use insert Code feature of netbeans which did all the job.

Comment: @latusaki - glad you got it working :)  Personally, I use Eclipse: a) Eclipse works well for both J2EE stuff as well as Android stuff, b) Eclipse is more IBM-friendly (and I work with IBM products), and c) Eclipse tends to have a larger "eco-system" (more 3rd party add-ons).  IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

The @WebServiceRef annotation is only supported in certain class types. Examples are JAX-WS endpoint implementation classes, JAX-WS handler classes, Enterprise JavaBeans classes, and servlet classes. This annotation is supported in the same class types as the @Resource annotation. See the Java Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE) 5 specification for a complete list of supported class types.

Answer (score 0):

I generally do it by creating an instance using the interface and the class.

```java
public class SimpleClient {

    // interface TimeServerBean_Service class TimeServerBean
    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "wsdl url here")
    static TimeServerBean_Service port = new TimeServerBean.getTimeServerBeanPort();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(port);
            System.out.println(port.methodWS("args"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //methods here
}
```